# Why the frequency spectrum of my OFDM output signal has a series of spike?

Tags: simulink, spectrum, ofdm

I'm trying to understand **OFDM modulation using Matlab Simulink** and I've built the following system

[image: OFDM TX]

I sent to the input of the OFDM block a frame of **15 samples** that comes from the **16-QAM modulator**. The OFDM modulator also receives a frame of **15 pilot symbols** that I have chosen (see below)

[image: PILOT]

Now, My OFDM block has the following settings:

[image: OFDM settings]

My question is, why the frequency spectrum of the output signal of the OFDM block has huge spikes?

[image: freq]

I have supposed to be the short FFT length compared to the number of pilot subcarriers but, I'm not sure about that

Thanks

Comment: hm, what *are* your pilot symbols? And the spectrum you show, how much did you average to get that spectrum? How white is your data?

Comment: @MarcusMüller pilot symbols are shown in the 2nd image. About the spectrum, I just used the Spectrum Analyzer of Simulink (it uses 1 Ohm as reference load)

Comment: ah, I thought that was just a snapshot of a single realization of the pilots; Hm. Could you give us an overall overview of the full graph from sources to spectrum analyzer, not just the excerpt?

Comment: @MarcusMüller the spectrum analyzer is connected directly at the last buffer on the right